# two rotated tables on same page as heading

Tags: tables, rotating

I am sorry, there seems to be a similar question already, but I didn't get the answer.
I have a chapter heading and then two wide but short tables with captions, which I would like to rotate. But after rotating they should be on the same page as the caption.

```
\chapter{Some caption}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}
[...some table...]
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}
[...some other table...]
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption2}
\end{table}
```

If I use sidewaystable, it puts the tables on a seperate page. I can also use:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{rotate}
\begin{tabular}
[...some table...]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}
[...some other table...]
\end{tabular}
\end{rotate}
\cation{combined caption 1 and 2}
\end{table}
```

but that will place the two tables alongside and not after each other. So if _ is the non rotated table and | the rotated table, I can get

```
caption
_
_
```

or

```
caption
|
|
```

but what i want is

```
caption
| |
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{combined caption for both rotated tables}
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
text \\
text \\
text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}\quad
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
text \\
text \\
text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you want your tables to appear at a specific location, perhaps you should consider *not* using a float object; you can use a `minipage` instead and you can provide a caption using `\captionof` from the caption or the capt-of packages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\captionof{figure}{combined caption for both rotated tables}
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
text \\
text \\
text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}\quad
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
text \\
text \\
text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Are you sure there isn't a better alternative than forcing the reader to rotate his/her head to read the tables?

Comment: same for your answer!: Wonderful! Thank you very much! And yes, I believe it is the best alternative. Its just a unit conversion table...

Comment: @user1638145 I've updated my answer providing an option that might be of interest for you.

Answer (score 3):

Will this do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{combined caption 1 and 2}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}%
}%
\hfil   %% just to demarkate
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
7 & 8  \\
4 & 5  \\
1 & 2  \\
\end{tabular}%
}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! simple and fast and just what I wanted!